# CKEditor 5 throws Cannot read property 'create' of undefined in Angular6 project

Tags: angular6, ckeditor5

I've created a project using JHipster and trying to create a WYSIWYG rich text editor using CKEditor 5. I've done the below steps by using the following [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular) to create an editor.

1. npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular
2. npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
3. Imported @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular and added in imports in my module.js
4. Imported @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic and created a variable public Editor: ClassicEditor; in my component
5. Used following code in html

> Blockquote

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

When I go to the page I added throws the following error which I got it from the browser developer tools console.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at CKEditorComponent.createEditor (ckeditor-ckeditor5-angular.js?076d:187)
    at eval (ckeditor-ckeditor5-angular.js?076d:96)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js?d135:388)
    at Zone.run (zone.js?d135:138)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js?09c9:3784)
    at CKEditorComponent.ngAfterViewInit (ckeditor-ckeditor5-angular.js?076d:95)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js?09c9:9568)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js?09c9:9542)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js?09c9:9532)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js?09c9:10468)
```

I'm just wondering if that's an issue with CKEditor 5 or did I miss any steps?

Comment: Could you show how you create the angular component?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Ramesh-ns/quill-editor-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/article/article-update.component.ts) is the link.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have the following code under the link:

```
export class ArticleUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    public Editor: ClassicEditor;
    // ...
}
```

While you should actually set the `ClassicEditor` to the `Editor` property, you only set it's type (which is actually wrong too, since the editor can have type `typeof ClassicEditor`).

What you should do is simple property assignment `public Editor = ClassicEditor;`, which will make the `ClassicEditor` available in the template under the `Editor` property.

This error can be also thrown when the import is incorrect - depending on the TypeScript configuration the import should look like `import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';` or  `import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`.

Comment: Thanks, Maciej for the solution! It worked. When I started initially, I've got a different error when I tried the solution you provided. I didn't realize it.

Comment: Did you encounter some other error related to this library later?

Comment: Yes, Maciej. I'm facing an issue with uploading an image. Do you recommend any plugins which are open source to upload an image and store it on my own server?

Comment: You can try this one: https://github.com/pourquoi/ckeditor5-simple-upload

Comment: I am already using approach `public Editor = BalloonEditor;` but still getting this error. any help?

Comment: Maybe you lack the import.

Comment: Could not find a declaration file for module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'. it says now after adding below suggested one import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

Answer (score 6):

Created a file **src/app/typings.d.ts** with below code

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' { // or other CKEditor 5 build.
const ClassicEditorBuild: any;

export = ClassicEditorBuild;}
```

Inside your **main app module**, import **CKEditorModule** as below:

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
@NgModule({imports: [CKEditorModule]})
```

Now, add import to the component where that issue was occurring in say **x.component.ts**

```
import * as ClassicEditorBuild from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

export class x implements OnInit { public Editor = ClassicEditorBuild;constructor() { }  ngOnInit(): void {}}
```

Finally, add below code in your **x.component.html**

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

Comment: The declaration in typings.d.ts solved the following error for me

Property 'create' is missing in type 'typeof import("D:/project/... /node_modules/@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-build-classic/index")' but required in type 'EditorConstructor'

Answer (score 3):

My solution was roughly the same as above, but as these didn't quite solve it, I tried:

```
public Editor: any = ClassicEditorBuild;
```

(adding `: any`)

which worked

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue even if you have this:

```
public Editor = BalloonEditor;
```

Check if you have in your template any call to the ckeditor component

For example:

```
<ckeditor formControlName="contenido"></ckeditor>
```

If you not set `[editor]="Editor"` it will produce same error.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring this

> public Editor: any = ClassicEditorBuild;

and in

> file
> ../../../../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/ckeditor.component.d.ts

change  **CKEDITOR_VERSION**: to any from string.